# How to update all matching keys of an object with another

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this

```
obj = {
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
}
```

and another object like this

```
other = {
a: 2
b: 2
}
```

How can I update obj to become this

```
result = {
a: 2
b: 2
c: 1
}
```

without explicitly saying

```
obj.a = other.a
obj.b = other.b
etc...
```

since I have a lot of values to update.

Comment: You can spread both into a resulting object, `const result = {...obj, ...other}` (note that if `other` has properties `obj` doesn't have, then this will add those properties also to the result)

Comment: In my case, other will never have properties that obj doesn't have. can you make this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)